# PowerQuery (M): How can I extract a date from a large text field?

Tags: excel, string, powerquery, excel-2016, m

My table has a text column called `Remarks` which usually contains a large amount of text.

**Here's an example:**
3/24/2017 11:14:41 AM - EMD FOR STATUS **NFU 3/30/17**
3/30/2017 10:58:03 AM - CLD PER RECEPTIONIST GM UNAVAILABLE **NFU 04-13-2017**
4/13/2017 11:10:15 AM - CLD PER RECEPTIONIST WILL GIVE INFO **NFU4/27**
4/27/2017 9:02:20 AM - MLD INV WITH 90 DAY STAMP
4/27/2017 9:15:03 AM - PER REP WILL CALL CUSTOMER FOR PAYMENT
4/27/2017 11:03:46 AM - **NFU 05/5**PER REP CUSTOMER CONFUSION
5/5/2017 8:55:17 AM - **NFU 5/9/2017** CRP PER REP CHECK WAS MLD 5/2/17

All of that text would be crammed into a single field, and I need to extract the last **NFU** date from the field for use in calculations and filtering.

In the above example, I would want to extract the date **5/9/2017** from the last row.
But as you can see, the date could be in any format, anywhere in the field.

I presume Excel can parse the text into a date value in any of the above formats (if not, I'll deal with that some other way - employee training, etc.)

The main things I need to figure out how to do using PowerQuery are:

- Find the last instance of "**NFU**" in this field
- Extract all text *immediately following* that last instance of "**NFU**", including the space between "**NFU**" and the date, if present.
  At this point, the result should be:
  `" 5/9/2017 CRP PER REP CHECK WAS MLD 5/2/17"`
- Remove any whitepsace at the beginning of the string.
  At this point, the result should be:
  `"5/9/2017 CRP PER REP CHECK WAS MLD 5/2/17"`
- Find the first character that is not `0-9`, `/`, or `-` (or the end of the string, whichever comes first)
- Truncate the string at the first non-date character, if appropriate.
  At this point, the result should be:
  `"5/9/2017"`
- Finally, attempt to format the resulting text into `Date` type/format, and return as the result for a PowerQuery custom column.

Looking at the PowerQuery string functions available, I'm not sure whether this is even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mean the Power Query **Text** functions. These are somewhat limited indeed, but there are plenty other options in Power Query's function library: in this case the List functions can come to the rescue.

By the way: I checked for " NFU" in order to avoid "CO**NFU**SION" (last but one line in your examples).

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Typed = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"example", type text}}),
    LastNFU = Table.AddColumn(Typed, "LastNFU", each Text.PositionOf([example]," NFU",Occurrence.Last), Int64.Type),
    AfterNFU = Table.AddColumn(LastNFU, "AfterNFU", each if [LastNFU] = -1 then null else Text.Range([example],[LastNFU]+4)),
    Trimmed = Table.TransformColumns(AfterNFU,{{"AfterNFU", Text.Trim}}),
    TextToList = Table.TransformColumns(Trimmed,{{"AfterNFU", each if _ = null then {} else Text.ToList(_)}}),
    ListFirstN = Table.TransformColumns(TextToList,{{"AfterNFU", each List.FirstN(_, each Text.Contains("01234567890-/",_))}}),
    TextCombine = Table.TransformColumns(ListFirstN, {"AfterNFU", Text.Combine, type text}),
    Date = Table.TransformColumnTypes(TextCombine,{{"AfterNFU", type date}}, "en-US"),
    Renamed = Table.RenameColumns(Date,{{"AfterNFU", "Date"}}),
    Removed = Table.RemoveColumns(Renamed,{"LastNFU"})
in
    Removed
```

Comment: This is perfect. I modified your solution a little, and combined it into a single (unreadable :) formula: `if [Remarks]<>null then if Text.PositionOf([Remarks],"NFU",Occurrence.Last)>=0 then Text.Combine(List.FirstN(Text.ToList(Text.Trim(Text.Range([Remarks],Text.PositionOf([Remarks],"NFU",Occurrence.Last)+3))),each Text.Contains("0123456789/-",_)),"") else Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()) else Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow())`

Comment: The only question left is, how can I tell if it failed to convert to `date` type? If it can't parse it as a date, I want to display the current date by default.

Comment: If it can't be parsed as a date, then the Table.TransformColumnTypes will produce errors that you can replace with the current date.

Answer (score -1):

A simple formula like =RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-(FIND("NFU",A1,1)-1)) would work to extract the string next to NFU. Assuming the text is at cell A1.
But needs to further drill down to get your other requirements.